# How to automatically add a shared libraries to cache in yocto

Tags: shared-libraries, embedded-linux, yocto

I am climbing the learning curve of Yocto (Honister) trying to add an third party executable ELF file to my Linux image.

My current issue is that the ELF requires a couple of shared libraries e.g. `libpam.so`. I have created a recipe that builds these libraries from source code and puts then in the correct place in the file system, but they are not being added to the shared library cache (e.g. not listed when you run `/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep pam` on the resulting system).

I can correct this manually on a running system via `/sbin/ldconfig /path/to/library` but I assume I am missing a something in my `do_install()` step or something.

My reading of the various docs suggest that the bitbake build process should automatically sort this out

---

On a side note the library version of [Linux-PAM](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/releases) is is 1.5.2 but the automake `Makefile.am` file specifies a version number of 0.85.1

`libpam_la_LDFLAGS = -no-undefined -version-info 85:1:85`

Is there a way I can access this `0.85.1` version number from an environment variable similar to `${PV}` (which returns `1.5.2`)

Thanks